# Probability of detecting at least two defects

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I am struggling with the correctness of my solution.
This is the problem:
Product produced in a factory has a probability of `0,27` to be defective. Factory control detects a defect in a probability of `0,99`  (it means it won't detect a defective product in a probability of `0,01`).
Question: what is the probability, that control between 5 products will find `not less than 2` defective ones?

My solution:
As I understood the question, they ask `the probability of at least two items will be defective.`

It means:

```
P(at least two) = 1 - P( no defects found) - P(one defect found)
```

I calculated `P(no defects found)` that way:

`f = 0.27` (probability of producing defective part)

`t = 1 - f = 0.73` (probability of producing a good part)

`b1 = 0.99` (probability of detecting a defected product)

`b2= 1 - b1 = 0.01` (probability of detecting a defected product)

Probabilities of P(no defects found) start there:

A0 = $t^5$ (all 5 parts are not defective)

A1 = $t^4$ * k * b2 (one defective, non found)

A2 = $t^3$ * $k^2$ * $b2^2$

A3 = $t^2$ * $k^3$ * $b2^3$ (three defective, non found)

...

A5 = $k^5$ * $b2^5$

```
P(one defect found) starts there:
```

B0 (no need to duplicate)

B1 = $t^4$ * k * b2 (one defective part, only one defect found)

B2 = $t^3$ * $k^2$ * b2 * b1 (two defective parts, only one defect found)

B3 = $t^2$ * $k^3$ * $b2^2$ * b1 (three defective parts, only one defect found)

...

B5 = $k^5$ * $b2^4$ * b1 (five defective parts, only one defect found)

So, the `P(zero)` is equal to `A0 + A1 + ... A5 = 0.2080767583`...

and `P(one found)` is equal to `B1 + B2 + ...+ B5 = 0.07619029792`

And `P(at least two)= 1 - P(zero) - P(one found) = 0.7157329438`

I don't know, is my solution correct and answer too, maybe there is another faster way to
calculate these possibilites

Comment: In my opinion the probability of detecting a defect product is missing. If you make a 2×2-table the column (row) of non-defective item is blank. The question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your analysis very difficult to wade through.  So, my (somewhat inferior) response will simply show how I would attack the problem.

I am making some assumptions about how the problem constraints are to be interpreted.  If I have misinterpreted the problem, please advise by leaving a comment, following this answer.

---

I am assuming that :

- The probability that a specific item is defective is $(0.27).$
- Assuming that a specific item is defective, the probability of the defect being detected is then $(0.99)$.
- There is no possibility of a false positive.  That is, if an item is not defective, then the testing will never falsely report that the item is defective.
- Therefore, the probability that any item is reported as defective is $(0.27) \times (0.99).$
- Testing of a specific item for a defect is independent of testing a separate item for a defect.  Therefore (for example), the probability of detecting a defect on two consecutive items is $~\displaystyle \left[ ~(0.27) \times (0.99) ~\right]^2.$

---

For simplicity of notation, let $~p = (0.27) \times (0.99),~$ and let $~q = (1-p).$

So, $~p~$ equals the probability that a specific item will be reported as defective, and $~q~$ equals the complementary probability that the item will not be reported as defective.

Assuming that exactly $~5~$ items are tested, 
for $~k \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5\},~$ 
let $~f(k)~$ denote the probability that exactly $k$ items are detected as defective.

Then, the desired computation is

$$1 - f(0) - f(1).$$

Then,

$$f(0) = \binom{5}{0}p^0q^{5-0} = q^5$$

and

$$f(1) = \binom{5}{1}p^1q^{5-1} = 5pq^4.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Final Computation}}$

$p = (0.27) \times (0.99).$ 
$q = 1-p.$

The probability of at least two defects being detected, out of five items tested, is

$$1 - q^5 - 5pq^4.$$

Comment: "There is no possibility of a false positive" This is an assumption you have made. I haven't found this information in the text.

Comment: Yes, You are right, correct part cannot be falsely detected, that good part by the control is detected as wrong one

Comment: @callculus42 Agreed, this is an assumption that I made.  Also, agreed that the problem statement does not address this issue.  This is why I specifically included this assumption in the list of assumptions that I was making, at the start of my answer.  Further, I was motivated to make this assumption because, unless I am mistaken, the problem can not be attacked without the assumption.  Problem composers don't normally intend to present Math students with a problem that can not be solved.  So, my **guess** is that this represents the problem composer's intent.

Comment: If I wuold face such an exercise I would answer, that this questions cannot be answered due lack of information.

Comment: But these are the questions and the thing is that it is harder to understand the question, how tricky they are, rather than just solving it

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the response!

Comment: I understood my mistake, Your response is logically correct, mine was only partly, while I was brute-forcing I did not include amount of overall possibilities to realize the conditions: I did not include, for instance, 1 choose 5 etc. , after providing changes into my brute-force calculations, the result proves to be correct, thanks!